# Enumerate Bytes of Unicode String

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have an interesting case where encodeURIComponent is not acting as an inverse of decodeURIComponent when dealing with unicode strings. Reproduction:

```js
let byteStr = "%17%c3%96%71"
let A = decodeURIComponent(byteStr);
let B = encodeURIComponent(A);
console.log("A",byteStr,"\n")
console.log("B",B,"\n")
console.log("EQUAL", B == byteStr)
```

Results

```
A %17%c3%96%71 

B %17%C3%96q 

EQUAL false
```

I would like convert `A` back into the same format as `byteStr`, but `encodeURIComponent` is designed to display ascii range characters when encountered. Is there a simple way to convert `A` back into its hex format shown in `byteStr`?

Enumerating over the individual bytes of a unicode string is the main issue. When I do `console.log(A.length)` the result is 3. While its unicode length may be "3" it still occupies 4 bytes. I've tried the following:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    console.log(A.charCodeAt(i).toString(16))
}
```

and the result is

```
17
d6
71
```

The `d6` portion is incorrect and should likely be two bytes instead of one. However, I'm not sure how to access the two bytes of the unicode string at this index.

Comment: What did you use to encode byteStr? The last few characters `%71` are correctly decoded to ascii letter `q`.  `decodeURIComponent(B) === A; // true`

Comment: You are correct that `%71` correctly encoded to letter `q`. However, I want the original format. This is used as part of JavaScript based encryption. I can write logic to convert the `q` after the fact but I'm looking for a simpler method if it exists

Comment: My point is, that encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent are the inverse and consistent. The question is what did you use to encode byteStr? And why is different than encodeURIComponent spec?

Comment: See RFC 3986, section 2.3 on unreserved characters. Unreserverved characters should not be percent-encoded. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.3

Comment: I completely understand the RFC and the fact that encodeURIComponent is not the true inverse of decodeURIComponent. I apologize for the misleading first statement. My goal is to concert the unicode string back into the original in an efficient way. Do you know of any efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. encodeURIComponent IS the true inverse of decodeURIComponent.

Comment: As to answer your question, you would need to know what created the original string. Which characters are percent-encoded? All characters?

Comment: If they aren't used as part of a URL, pass them without encoding. If they are used as part of a URL, maybe you'll have better luck with base64 encoding.

Comment: Yes, all characters should be percent-encoded

Comment: For additional context that may have been lost, the original encoded text came from a custom cryptographic routine that an application was using to encode and encrypt data. It was not produced by `encodeURIComponent` directly. Instead, it was produced by a byte stream that represented data that the app was collecting. I was reverse engineering the app to find ways to reproduce the encoding and encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most concise way to do this is to use a **TextEncoder**, which will convert the unicode string into an array of bytes that can be iterated over. This appears to be the best way to enumerate the bytes of a unicode string.

```
let unicodeStr = "˜∑π¬"
let byteArr = Array.from(new TextEncoder().encode(unicodeStr))

for (let i = 0; i < byteArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(byteArr[i].toString(16));
}
```